# Unable to RDP Windows 7 using Remmina on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote-desktop

It appears since late of last week there is no longer the ability to RDP onto Windows 7 using the linux client Remmina. Nothing (configuration) has changed on the linux client nor the Windows 7 host with the exception of security updates being installed.

When attempting to log in, i am able to get as far as being presented a prompted with the challenge to accept the certificate however as soon as i click to accept the session closes immediately.

I am able to ping, telnet, etc the host device. No firewall rules have been changed. I have also followed all suggestions below;

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/157723/cannot-rdp-to-windows-7-with-remmina-on-12-04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/154121/why-wont-remmina-connect-to-windows-7-remote-desktop

Neither works.

I had to follow the suggestion at to get it to work however it is less than ideal

- https://serverfault.com/questions/574759/linux-rdesktop-error-recv-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: Remmina uses xfreerdp to do its underlying connection, you can use it from the command line `xfreerdp /v:<ip.of.rdp.server> /u:username /p:` this will then connect to your server and hopefully give you some debug info if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with one server too and I'm posting this because I hadn't see this specific solution anywhere. Maybe it helps someone.

---

I've tried to connect manually with `xfreerpd` :

```
xfreerdp -d my-login-domain.com -u username -v myserver.com
```

And got this:

> **[INFO][com.freerdp.core] - ERRINFO_LICENSE_HWID_DOESNT_MATCH_LICENSE (0x00000104):The Client Access License ([MS-RDPELE] section 1.1) stored by the client has been modified**.
>
> [INFO][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Logon Error Info SESSION_ID [UNKNOWN]
>
> [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

So I deleted the Client Access License in:

```
~/.config/freerdp/licenses/BIG-HASH-FILENAME.cal
```

And also deleted (no need to delete the file, just remove the right row):

```
~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2
```

That's it, restart the application and try again.

PS: (I'm using Fedora 29 and Remmina 1.2.31.3)

Comment: I had a ERRINFO_LICENSE_HWID_DOESNT_MATCH_LICENSE error after upgrading freerdp from version 2.0.0_rc4 to 2.1.2. Deleting the license file in ~/.config/freerdp/licenses/ fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run 'remmina' form commandline to watch output and deduce the root cause.

I was able to solve by:

1. Deleting my windows self-signed certificate and rebooting so that it would re-create a new one. (mmc.exe>file>add snap-in>certificates>computer account>local computer then Certificates>Remote Desktop>certificates: delete the existing cert)
2. Then remove the known certificate for remmina/xfreerdp:

   - purge or modify ~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2
   - purge or modify ~/.freerdp/known_hosts
   - (depending on remmina/distribution versions)